# How can I configure the default MR title & message via push options in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, git-push

GitLab has a long-standing issue to make MR titles & messages configurable; see [Ability to customise default merge request title (#16080)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/16080).

Unfortunately the change [Set default MR title/description to first multi-line commit (!52984)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/52984) has made the default title & message even more frustrating for many users. Unless you are really thinking hard about your first multiple-line commit, given you even know how this works, you can get some really bizarre defaults for your MR title & message. Users could write a `git commit --allow-empty` message early in their history, but we aren't always creating MRs for history we can still edit. In many cases you may not even want a complicated title & message, if you believe the code is a better place to put documentation (e.g. in a new commit at the *end* of history).

Is there a simple way to set up an `alias` or git alias to make this configurable via a push option? See [Push Options | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html) for the exposed settings.

I've been using this long alias in my global git config file. The non-empty `merge_request.description` is necessary because if you only set the MR title the MR message *still* gets the message from the first multi-line commit ☹.

```
pm = "!f() { git push -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.description=x -o merge_request.title=${2} ${1} ${2}; }; f"
```

That is, rather than `git push remote branch-name` I run `git pm remote branch-name`. Unfortunately auto-complete doesn't work with this kind of alias. Am I missing some simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: So, if I'm understanding you correctly, the solution you have _works_, but the only drawback is you don't get auto-complete for the alias? Would you consider [adding completions for aliases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4219/how-do-i-get-bash-completion-for-command-aliases) a possible solution/workaround?

Comment: Right. That is a solution and I'd explored it a bit but didn't want to commit to adding a dependency like `complete_alias`; maybe it is the best for the situation though.

Comment: Another downside to the existing solution is that it doesn't let you add any extra push options (e.g. `merge_request.target`). Another solution might be to expand an alias into the command line with the extra arguments.

Comment: Yeah, to overcome the extra options issue, you might use `shift` to pop off the first positional arguments then use `$@` to pass the remaining arbitrary arguments.